# WordPress Multisite get_sites() array only has first 99 sites

Tags: php, wordpress, multisite

I have a WordPress multisite installation with about 125 different sites at the moment. I have a plugin that has specific multisite functionality, however, it cannot be used to modify many of my sites because it is only listing the first 99 sites. It uses get_sites() to list the sites so I tried using the following command and only 99 of 125 sites were listed in the array:

```
 $testeroo = get_sites();
 print_r(array_values($testeroo));
```

Does anyone with multisite experience know of a reason why get_sites() would not list all of the sites on the installation? All of the sites appear properly in Network Admin->Sites.

Answer (score 2):

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_sites/

> 'number'
>   (int) Maximum number of sites to retrieve. Default 100.

Set that parameter to something absurdly high, or use the `offset` parameter to paginate.

Comment: THANK YOU! I see now, they changed 'limit' to 'number' which is what was breaking the plugin. You're a hero!

Comment: Just noting that using -1, as in 'get all' like we use in similar situations like with WP_Query, does not appear to work here.